# Discord bot | SQLite-Based Points System

Tags: sql, bots, discord.js

I'm kind of new to programming, so forgive me if the problem is stupid. I'm creating a Discord bot, practicing JS, but I wanted an XP/levelling system, which is too much for me, so I followed this guide here:

https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/sqlite-based-points-system

My code is therefore 100% identical to the one in that page, and everything does work perfectly, but one thing: when displaying the leaderboard, the users ID are not displayed correctly; instead, "undefined" is shown. Also, when opening the .sqlite file and checking the ID tab, it says "undefined", and I could manually type in the ID, but needless to say it shouldn't work like that.

Is there any part of that code that is not updated, or something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That guide is outdated as since discord.js v12 you need to use [`client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager) cache or you can use the [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) method.

I am assuming you're referring to the snippet below that's found on the page you linked, it was inside the `leaderboard` command.

```js
for(const data of top10) {

embed.addField(client.users.get(data.user).tag, `${data.points} points (level ${data.level})`);

}
```

In this snippet, replace `client.users.get(data.user).tag` with `client.users.cache.get(data.user).tag`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. 

I had actually found out that `fetch()` was the right method to use, but I still run into the same issue.
Also, there is no error message whatsoever in my terminal.

EDIT: the first method you posted was the one I actually used, which didn't work. I have now tried the 2nd one, which actually worked. Thank you!

Comment: You should **not** use `find(x => x.id === myid)` instead of `get(myid)`.